# How do I use pre_option_{option_name} correctly?

Tags: hooks

I am using a filter to decrypt an api_key that is stored with encryption. I have registered the following hook:

```php
// Decrypt API key after it is retrieved
add_filter('pre_option_percify_api_key', array( __CLASS__, 'decrypt_api_key') );
```

The problem is, I cannot get at the stored value in the callback:

```php
public static function decrypt_api_key($encrypted) {
  // $encrypted is empty:

  echo($encrypted);
  // ...
```

Am I calling the function correctly? How do I access the stored value of `percify_api_key` within `decrypt_api_key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pre_option_{$option}` hook is used to filter the value of the option **before** it's retrieved. You need to hook after the value is retrieved so you can manipulate it.

In this case, you can use the `option_{$option}` hook. So your code will look like this:

```php
add_filter('option_percify_api_key', array( __CLASS__, 'decrypt_api_key') );
```

For more info - take a look at the source of the `get_option` function [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/option.php#L77). Specifically line [#225](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/option.php#L225).